# Show database in MySQL into HTML JSP Page

Tags: html, jsp

I'm new to JSP, I made a jsp file in my ROOT folder in Tomcat directory to show database in MySQL table.
Here is my code in mysql.jsp:

```html
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

<form method="get">

<table border="1">
   <tr>
        <td>User ID</td>
        <td>Group ID</td>
   </tr>
   <%
   try
   {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activiti";
       String username="root";
       String password="123456";
       String query="select * from act_id_membership";
       Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
       Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
       while(rs.next())
       {
   %>
           <tr><td><%=rs.getString("USER_ID_") %></td></tr>
           <tr><td><%=rs.getString("GROUP_ID_") %></td></tr>
   <%
       }
   %>
   </table>
   <%
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   %>
</form>
```

And this is my MySQL Database:
[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6wLf.png)

And when I run it with http://localhost:8080/mysql.jsp in my browser, it show 2 columns into 1 column:
[On JSP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBqG.png)

I'm not familiar with HTML code so I really don't know how to fix this. Can anyone tell me how to show it with 2 columns like my database? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html as below:

```
  {
       %>
               <tr>
                   <td><%=rs.getString("USER_ID_") %></td>
                   <td><%=rs.getString("GROUP_ID_") %></td>
               </tr>
       <%
  }
```